# How can I set timeout for Google's Vision API

Tags: python, google-vision

I'm using Python to make a query to Google's Vision API to obtain labels from an image, but I'm not able to set a timeout in case I don't receive a response within a given time.

I'm using the following code based on [Google's Documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/gax-python/latest/gax-python.pdf) of CallOptions.

This is my code:

```
class GoogleQuery():

def __init__(self, VisionTools):
    self.client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    self.QueryOptions = google.gax.CallOptions(timeout=0.1)

... more init fields

def QueryImage(self, frame):
    image = types.Image(content=frame)

    # Make query to Google
    response = self.client.label_detection(image=image, options=self.QueryOptions)
```

I have tried passing directly the arguments into the call to Google without success, like this:

```
    def QueryImage(self, frame):

        # Convert frame to a type compatible with Google API
        image = types.Image(content=frame)

        # Make query to Google
        o1 = CallOptions(timeout = 0.1)
        response = self.client.label_detection(image=image, options=(o1))
```